# Dot plots (as opposed to dotplots) in R

Tags: r, graphics, plot, fonts

I am trying to write a function that will produce what I regard as a *real* dot plot (unlike the Cleveland variety, I require a univariate scatterplot with the dots stacked for (nearly) equal values). I have come close:

[image]

In this illustration, the dots you see are actually rotated text strings of lower-case "o"s. It is done this way because I need the dot spacing to stay constant if the plot is re-scaled. However, I'd like something better than lower-case "o"s, for example, filled dots instead of circles. This could be done if I could access the font that is used for the standard plotting symbols (`pch = 1:25` in the `plot` function and relatives). Then I could make a text string with that font and get what's needed. Does anybody know how to do that?

PS - No, a histogram with lots of bins is not an acceptable substitute.

Comment: Cant you just add points to a plot with `points()`? There's not really a plotting "font." Without code or data this really isn't a programming question that we can help with.

Comment: @MrFlick - No, because the spacing between the points depends on the vertical size of the graph. As I tried to explain, I want the points to be a character width apart no matter what the scaling.

Answer (score 2):

I did find a way to get the desired dot plot using low-level graphics parameters (namely "usr", the actual user coordinates of the plotting area, and "cxy", the character size). The `recordGraphics()` function wraps the part that needs to be changed when the graph is resized. Here's the function:

```
dot.plot = function(x, pch = 16, bins = 50, spacing = 1, xlab, ...) {
  if(missing(xlab))
    xlab = as.character(substitute(x))

  # determine dot positions
  inc = diff(pretty(x, n = bins)[1:2])
  freq = table(inc * round(x / inc, 0))
  xx = rep(as.numeric(names(freq)), freq)
  yy = unlist(lapply(freq, seq_len))

  # make the order of the dots the same as the order of the data
  idx = seq_along(x)
  idx[order(x)] = idx
  xx = xx[idx]
  yy = yy[idx]

  # make a blank plot
  plot(xx, yy, type = "n", axes = FALSE, xlab = xlab, ylab = "")

  # draw scale
  axis(1)
  ylow = par("usr")[3]
  abline(h = ylow) # extend to full width

  # draw points and support resizing
  recordGraphics({
      yinc = 0.5 * spacing * par("cxy")[2]
      points(xx, ylow + yinc * (yy - .5), pch = pch, ...)
    },
    list(),
    environment(NULL))

  invisible()
}
```

The `spacing` argument may be used if you want a tighter or looser gap between dots. An example...

```
with(iris, dot.plot(Sepal.Length, col = as.numeric(Species)))
```

[image: Dot plot of sepal length colored by species]

This is a better solution than trying to do it with text, but also a little bit scary because of the warnings you see in the documentation for `recordGraphics`